# GQL Substring Match

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine, gql

Suppose that on my site there is a form which allows users to search for book titles within my database.

How can I perform substring matches?

For example, the query "caTCher" should return "Catcher in the Rye".

```
db.GqlQuery("SELECT title FROM Book WHERE " + titleQuery + " IN title")
```

The above query doesn't work (and shouldn't work), but I think it should take a similar shape.

I haven't found any helpful information despite this being a, seemingly, common use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to convert the input string into the format of the strings in your database. [SearchableModel](http://justgagan.com/post/24880403834/google-app-engine-full-text-search-support-in) will do the rest of the search for the partial string of the title (It will only work for full words such as catcher, not catche or cat). It will create a list of all single words in your titles column and reference back to the original entry (for example, called titleStrList). Then you search for something like:

```
*Do your regex stuff here*
db.GqlQuery("SELECT title FROM Book WHERE " + titleQuery + " IN titleStrList")
```

Comment: Apologies, it looks like the page has been taken down. I have updated the link, it will show you an example of extending this module to use full text search support and is based upon authors and books coincidentally, hopefully this helps.